# fseek now supports large files

Tags: c++, 64-bit, large-files, fseek

It appears that fseek now, at least in my implementation, supports large files naturally without fseek64, lseek or some strange compiler macro.

When did this happen?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
void writeF(const char*fname,size_t nItems){
  FILE *fp=NULL;
  if(NULL==(fp=fopen(fname,"w"))){
    fprintf(stderr,"\t-> problems opening file:%s\n",fname);
    exit(0);
  }
  for(size_t i=0;i<nItems;i++)
    fwrite(&i,sizeof(size_t),1,fp);
  fclose(fp);
}
void getIt(const char *fname,size_t offset,int whence,int nItems){
  size_t ary[nItems];
  FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"r");
  fseek(fp,offset*sizeof(size_t),whence);
  fread(ary,sizeof(size_t),nItems,fp);

  for(int i=0;i<nItems;i++)
    fprintf(stderr,"%lu\n",ary[i]);
  fclose(fp);
}


int main(){
  const char * fname = "temp.bin"; 
  writeF(fname,1000000000);//writefile
  getIt(fname,999999990,SEEK_SET,10);//get last 10 seek from start
  getIt(fname,-10,SEEK_END,10);//get last 10 seek from start
  return 0;
}
```

The code above writes a big file with the entries 1-10^9 in binary size_t format.
And then writes the last 10 entries, seeking from the beginning of the file, and seek from the end of file.

Comment: I thought fseek only goes up to 2GB but I don't see 2GB worth of files here.

Comment: @monkeyking - IOW, 1000000000 = 1,000,000,000 and 999999990 = 999,999,990, neither of these is > 2GB

Comment: Also, you fail to mention platform... duh

Answer (score 1):

Linux x86-64 has had large file support (LFS) from pretty much day one; and doesn't require any special macros etc to enable it - both traditional `fseek()`) and LFS `fseek64()` already use a 64bit `off_t`.

Linux i386 (32bit) typically defaults to 32-bit `off_t` as otherwise it would break a huge number of applications - but you can test what is defined in your environment by checking the value of the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` macro.

See http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html for full details on Linux large file support.

Answer (score 1):

The signature is

```
int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );
```

so the range depends on the size of `long`.

On some systems it is 32-bit, and you have a problem with large files, on other systems it is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

`999999990` is a normal int and fits perfectly into 32 bits. I don't believe that you'd get away with this though:

```
getIt(fname,99999999990LL,SEEK_SET,10);
```